# is there an API out there to access google page rank for a predefined set of keywords?

Tags: google-analytics

I am building an internal reporting tool that I want to update with Googles pagerank once per week.

The list of keywords would be predefined at this point.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

They do have an Adwords API that may get you closer to what you are looking to do.

API - http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/

Specifically the [TrafficEstimatorService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TrafficEstimatorService.html) allows you to specify keyword parameters and estimate what traffic you could receive.

Comment: Gotcha,I'll take a look.  I use SEOMOZ and I want to be able to deliver a similar item to their Page Rank tool...